# Restricting file running via cron job from direct access

Tags: php, html, cron

I need advise regarding safeguarding a file i created that runs on via cronjobs.

Currently, i'm using HTTP_referrer from preventing direct access from unauthorised person. But will this also prevent my cron jobs from executing it as well.

I inserted the following code at the top of my script:

```
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        echo 'Restricted Access';
        exit;
    }
```

Is this secure and will it prevent access from my cron? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you executing the scripts from CLI or using something like wget to call a URL?

Comment: place the file outside of webroot or use .htaccess

Answer (score 3):

**Using Cron + PHP CLI to execute the script:**

Do not put that file under webroot.

**Using Cron + Wget to request the script:**

Pass a secret key to your script via post; check that key in your script. Example:

Content of key.txt which resides on the server outside wwwroot:

```
key=hello
```

Wget command line

```
wget --post-file=key.txt http://example.com/cron.php
```

PHP script

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("key.txt"), $array);
if($array != $_POST)
    die("does not match");
```